# Retrieve specific type of activity from vactivity feed Youtube api V3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to retrieve only certain type of activities of the youtube api v3 activites list. there are so many types:

-bulletin
-channelItem
-comment
-favorite
-like
-playlistItem
-recommendation
-social
-subscription
-upload

I want to be able to retrieve only upload,comment and recommendation. How would I do that? I have the following request and this retrieves all types:

```
function requestVideoPlaylist() {
    var requestOptions = {
    home: 'true',
    part: 'snippet, contentDetails',
    maxResults: 8
  };



  var request = gapi.client.youtube.activities.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {


    var activityItems = response.result.items;

});}
```

Comment: Right now, you can't filter this feed based on the activity type, so your only option would be to filter it on your end.

Comment: @jlmcdonald do you know a simple way to do the filtering?

Comment: He's referring to using a loop and an if statement to find the activities you care about.

Comment: ohh okay! yh i used an array.filter method in jquery and it worked! thanks :)